# Weblogic 10g to Oracle 12/19C Data Source connectivity

Tags: datasource, oracle12c, weblogic-10.x

When i create a data source from my Weblogic version 10.3.3.0 to Oracle Database 12C.
I get the below error :-

```
Connection test failed.
Message icon - Error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied <br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:406)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:799)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:368)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)<br/>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)<br/>com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:505)<br/>com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:458)<br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)<br/>sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)<br/>java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)<br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)<br/>...
```

I have checked my creds and jdbc string but not sure what's going wrong.

Any suggestions , please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you use a simple [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java) to connect successfully. Make sure all your credentials are correct.